# Rails nested form is doubling up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Using nested forms in a rails 4 app using paperclip, and images(:img) are doubling up when i edit the post. For example having one image result in show 2, but the database shows only one entry.

_form.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
 <%= f.fields_for :images do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'image_fields', f: builder %>
 <% end %>
</fieldset>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add New Image", f, :images %>
```

_image_fields.html.erb

```
<% @article.images.each do |a| %>
<div class="form-group">        
 <fieldset>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <%= image_tag a.img(:thumb) %>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-10">
 <%= f.input :img, label: false  %>
 </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

_form.html.erb

```
 <fieldset>
   <% @article.images.each do |image| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :images, image do |builder| %>
       <%= render partial: 'image_fields', locals: { f: builder, image: image } %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
</fieldset>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add New Image", f, :images %>
```

_image_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">        
 <fieldset>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <%= image_tag image.img(:thumb) %>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-10">
 <%= f.input :img, label: false  %>
 </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks phlegx. I get the error: **undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x007f8cd3eb3b58>:0x007f8cd2d35c78>**

Comment: @DollarChills see my changes in `<%= render partial: 'image_fields', ...`